Mapping cone homotopy equivalent to quotient Space
In the paper Derived categories for the working mathematician on page 8 the author states that the mapping cone $C_f$ of a continuous map $f: X \to Y$ of topological spaces is homotopy equivalent to the quotient space $Y/X$ if $f$ is an inclusion.
I tried to construct the homotopy equivalence:
Define a map $ g: \mathrm{C}_{f} \to Y/X $ by sending elements of $ Y \setminus X $ (white elliptical section in the pictures in the paper) to itself and the whole glued cone to the one point $X$ in the quotient (gray ellipse). Define the other map $ h: Y/X \to \mathrm{C}_{f} $ by sending again $ Y \setminus X $ to itself and the one point $X$ from the quotient to the apex of the cone.
It is evident that $ gh $ is just the identity on $ Y/X $ and thus homotopic to the identity. The other composition $ hg $ may however not be the identity since $ hg $ shrinks the whole cone to its own apex. Anyways, I need to show that this map is homotopic to the identity on $C_f$. But I am not even sure if this map is continuous. If it was continuous and I would want to construct the homotopy map
$$H: C_f \times [0,1] \to C_f$$
the canonical way (at least I think) is $H(z,0)=hg(z)$ and $H(z,1)=\mathrm{id}_{C_f}(z)$ and for $t \in (0,1)$, $H(\bullet, t)$ should be the map where the glued cone gets shrunk to the cone with height $t$.
Is this the right construction? I am somehow struggling a lot seeing whether these are even continuous.

Do you know what a cofibration is? For general inclusions I don't think it is true.

@VincentBoelens Ah, I see. He mentions that if $f$ is a cofibration that works, but that means inclusions for purposes of the paper. But actually no, i do not know what that is.

To strengthen @VincentBoelens suspicion, it's not true. If you have a subspace inclusion $\iota\colon A \hookrightarrow X$, then you can define the relative (ordinary) homology of the pair $(X, A)$ as $H_(X, A) = H_(C_f)$. It's a theorem that this agrees with $\tilde{H}*(X / A)$ when $\iota$ is a cofibration. For a counterexample, you can take the inclusion $\iota\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to S^2$: $S^2 / \mathbb{R}^2$ is contractible, but from the l.e.s. in homology you see that $H_2(C\iota) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

@Ben Steffan Ok, but  if $f$ was a cofibration, do you think the homotopy map from above would work?

@FlynnFehre If $f$ was a cofibration I would not try to construct an explicit homotopy :^) In any case, your map $h$ is not continuous (in general) so the answer is no. After all, it's image is ${\text{cone point}} \cup Y \setminus X$ which is disconnected. The point is that to define an inverse $h$ you somehow need to use some data (namely, a homotopy) to connect this over the rest of the cone; this is precisely what a cofibration allows you to do.

@BenSteffan I see. As it seems to be not as easy as it looked I will leave it as is at the moment. Thank you for the comments.

This is true if $f$ is a (Hurewicz) cofibration. This uses two facts. First, the pushout of a cofibration is again a cofibration, i.e. if $f\colon X\to Y$ is a cofibration and $P$ is the pushout of $Y\leftarrow X\to Z$, then $Z\to P$ is a cofibration. This fact can be found in most textbooks (for instance tom Dieck's book or Peter May's lectures). Second, if $A$ is contractible and $A\to X$ is a cofibration, $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.
Assuming this, note that $Cf$ is the pushout of $CX\leftarrow X\xrightarrow{f} Y$ and if $f$ is a cofibration, also $CX\to Cf$ is. The natural map $Y/X\to Cf/CX$ is a homeomorphism and $CX$ is contractible, so this yields the claim.
That $X\to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence if $A$ is contractible and $A\to X$ a cofibration is a straightforward application of the homotopy extension property. Let $h\colon A\times I\to A$ be a homotopy between the identity of $A$ and a constant map with value $a_0\in A$ and denote by $h\colon A\times I\to X$ also its composition with $A\to X$. Extend this to a homotopy $H\colon X\times I\to X$ with initial condition the identity of $X$ (i.e. $H(x,0)=x$ for all $x\in X$). Then $H(a,1) = h(a,1) = a_0$ for all $a\in A$, which means that $H(-,1)$ factors as a map $X\to X/A\to X$.

Ok, so I do not know half of the stuff that is written here. But I believe that this could be helpful for someone who might wonder the same as I did and has the right knowledge. So, I'll accept it :)

@FlynnFehre Judging from what you wrote in your question you should be able to understand everything, maybe it is a question of terminology. In the nLab page, only definition 2.1 is relevant (left homotopy is just homotopy).
